# Sort array of structs alphabetically by char vector

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct, char

I'm trying to sort an array of structs by a char vector defined within. I'm not allowed to use strings in this particular problem, and I'm a bit lost on how I'd sort alphabetically.

The problem is reading a text file, and using string pools, sort alphabetically.
I read the file and add the characters to a struct, which I treat as a word. I'm storing the 'word' as a vector of chars (I know, it's messy).

I've worked out I can probably sort with this logic (minus the cycling through the char array):

```
min = lowest scoring word
for loop i
  for loop j
    if (word[j] < min)
      min = word[j]
    endif
   endfor
endfor
```

I've done this to sort by the first letter, but it's pretty unreliable.

```
struct wordCounter{
    int startIndex, numOfTimes = 1;
    std::vector<char> word;
};
...
wordCounter counter[wordCount]; // wordCount assigned using string pool maths
...
for (int x = 0; x < wordCount; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < wordCount; y++) {
        if (counter[x].numOfTimes == counter[y].numOfTimes) {
            if (counter[x].word[0] < counter[y+1].word[0]) {
                wordCounter wordTemp = counter[x];
                counter[x] = counter[y];
                counter[y] = wordTemp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Moar example code.

Comment: @Motes I don't have anything related to the logic in actual C++, but what I do have is now in the post.

Comment: show how one defines the `struct`

Comment: @Motes ah sorry. Added now

Comment: One needs to take the length into account of each vector, like 'while( i < counter[y].word.size()) { while( i < counter[x].word.size()) { //compare } if ( i == counter[x].size() ) { //then one knows word of counter x was equal to counter[y] for all the lenght of x } }  if ( i == counter[y].size() ) { //then one knows word of counter y was equal to counter x] for all the length of y } }` then maybe check if both are the same length and maybe both are completely equal so then just arbitrarily choose one if no minimum was found that round

Comment: Also when one finds the minimum, swap it with the one at the top of the array and then make the inner loop only start at `int y = x` so one doesn't check the ones already minimized.

Comment: `i` in the above would be the current char position being checked as well, consider that instead of always checking `word[0]`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `std::sort` function? If so, that removes one obstacle and you're left with just having to write a comparator function. Although not *trivial*, that is relatively straightforward.

Comment: But, even if `std::sort` is not allowed, you're going to be better off separating your task into functions, so you should still be thinking of that comparator as a separate "work unit".